# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot in Vue component

Tags: css, vue.js

I have a Bootstrap template that worked fine before implementing Vue.JS, after that this error came out:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot'

And this the CSS code which located in a styles.css file that causes this error:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
  src: local("Material Icons"), local("MaterialIcons-Regular"),
    url(../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format("woff2"),
    url(../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format("woff"),
    url(../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: check that the file exists

Comment: And how do I know that?